# issue with exit condition of loop?

Tags: java, arraylist, do-while

I am trying to use a while condition where if a user inputs a string with the first character as number 1, the loop should end. However, in my case the loop never ends. What could I be doing wrong?

```
public static void main(String[] args) { 

   ArrayList<Integer> instructions = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    String input = "";
    String termIns = input.substring(0);
   // int termInsInt= Integer.parseInt(termIns);

    do {
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        instructions.add(inputInt);
        //String termIns = input.substring(0);

    } while(!termIns.equals("1"));
```

In addition, what would display the list of all elements in the ArrayList?

Comment: Where do you update `termIns` value? Also what is the purpose of `substring(0)` (this doesn't do anything)?

Comment: Anyway if you want to check if some string has some value at start simply use `yourString.startsWith(someValue)`.

Comment: Tip: Use `!"1".equals(termIns)` as calling `.equals` on a String constant cannot throw a null pointer exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to update `termIns` with the user input in each iteration of loop:

```
do {
        input = keyboard.nextLine();
        int inputInt = Integer.parseInt(input);
        instructions.add(inputInt);
        termIns = input.substring(0);

    } while(!termIns.equals("1"));
```

Also `substring(0)` will not help you as

> substring(int beginIndex)
>
> Returns a new string that is a substring of
>   this string. The substring begins with the character at the specified
>   index and extends to the end of this string.

You can use [startsWith](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith(java.lang.String)) method instead directly on input as mentioned here

```
while(!input.startsWith("1"))
```

Comment: Thanks Juned, however, when I entered the following, numbers 230, 430, 630, 730, 120, 1; it did not exit the loop when I entered 120 and exited when I entered 1. I should have exited the loop at 120 as well since the first character is "1" in 120. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

you're not updating termsIn which is part of your terminating condition.

Also, you can display all the elements in the Arraylist by creating a loop outside of your do-while that prints out all the elements in your arraylist. I'd take a look at the javadoc on Arraylist.